# "pandas python" group values either as a list or string based on a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that has a column called id and I want to group other columns accordingly. Meaning that one id one row and other columns grouped as a list of many values for the same id or as a string of one value for that id

I tried many solutions including the one mentioned below but could not get the desired output

```
def group_values(df):
   for col in columns:
        if  col != id:
            df[col] = df.groupby('id')[col].apply(list).reset_index(name=col)['col']
return df
```

**Current data frame**

```
index   id      col1    col2
0       11        23      40
1       11        34      90
2       11        87      86
3       30        43      54
```

**Desired output**

```
index   id          col1              col2
0       11        [23,34, 87]       [40,90, 86]
1       30           43                  54
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22.0/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html):

```
In [1829]: df.groupby('id').agg({'col1': list, 'col2': list}).reset_index()
Out[1829]: 
   id          col1          col2
0  11  [23, 34, 87]  [40, 90, 86]
1  30          [43]          [54]
```

Comment: Actually, the expected output is to not list `index`, so something like this `df.groupby('id').agg({'col1': list, 'col2': list}).reset_index()` would be needed.

Comment: Oh, yes you are right! Updated my answer.  Thanks for that.